# ERC20 token minting with AccessControl

Tags: reactjs, solidity, erc20

I created a ERC20 token with unlimited supply with mint and burn functionality. For the access control, I followed [OpenZeppelin AccessControl Documentation](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/access-control).

Here is a sample code from the documentation:
[image]

How do I set the MINTER_ROLE and BURNER_ROLE to users who are eligible to do it in a ReactJs Project. Is it possible?

Or any other way that I can check who are eligible to mint?

I'm trying to create same as minting functionality of SLP token and VIS token on their website.So eligibility for minting depends on certain conditions. Smart contract is not a problem as documentation is well written. Just don't know how to set roles using reactJs.

Answer (score 0):

The sample contract is below. Only ADMIN_ROLE can setup or revoke MINTER/BURNER roles. Now, from your ReactJs application, you need to use [web3js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html) or [ethersjs](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/getting-started/#getting-started--contracts) libraries to interact with deployed MyToken contract by sending `setupMinter` and `setupBurner` transactions. Those transactions must be sent by that account with ADMIN_ROLE, the contract deployer in our case. You can update `setupMinter` and `setupBurner`functions for different logic, but the main idea must be clear.

```
contract MyToken is ERC20, AccessControl {
    bytes32 public constant ADMIN_ROLE = keccak256("ADMIN_ROLE");
    bytes32 public constant MINTER_ROLE = keccak256("MINTER_ROLE");
    bytes32 public constant BURNER_ROLE = keccak256("BURNER_ROLE");

    constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "TKN") {
        _setupRole(ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender);
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyRole(MINTER_ROLE) {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }

    function burn(address from, uint256 amount) public onlyRole(BURNER_ROLE) {
        _burn(from, amount);
    }

    /// @dev Grants or revokes MINTER_ROLE
    function setupMinter(address minter, bool enabled) external onlyRole(ADMIN_ROLE) {
        require(minter != address(0), "!minter");
        if (enabled) _setupRole(MINTER_ROLE, minter);
        else _revokeRole(MINTER_ROLE, minter);   
    }

    /// @dev Grants or revokes BURNER_ROLE
    function setupBurner(address burner, bool enabled) external onlyRole(ADMIN_ROLE) {
        require(burner != address(0), "!burner");
        if (enabled) _setupRole(BURNER_ROLE, burner);
        else _revokeRole(BURNER_ROLE, burner);   
    }    

    /// @dev Returns true if MINTER
    function isMinter(address minter) external view returns(bool) {
        return hasRole(MINTER_ROLE, minter);
    }

    /// @dev Returns true if BURNER
    function isBurner(address burner) external view returns(bool) {
        return hasRole(BURNER_ROLE, burner);
    }    
}
```

https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/access-control#granting-and-revoking